# how to add leading zero to a text field in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, formula, leading-zero, crystal-reports-formulas

I'm trying to think of a way to add a leading zero to a string field value. 
For example I have 12345 but need a formula that would convert it to 012345. I'm new to Crystal as I know that this is probably a simple formula but cant seem to get it to work.

```
12345 => 012345  (add leading zero to make it 6 chars)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the values always the same length, or do you need pad a number up to a certain number of places with zeroes?  For example 12345 becomes `012345` and 2 becomes `000002`.

Comment: I used Ryan's answer, but does anyone know if there is an even easier way to do this, without creating a new formula? There is in fact a setting under formatting for number fields called "Leading Zero", but ticking it does nothing. Seems most people finding this answer could use that info too.

Answer (score 7):

Try this

> totext(your_number, "000000");

1st arg.: Well, it's the input.

2nd arg.: Number of digits you need in the output.

For ex,

> num = 1234;
>
> totext(num, "000000");

Output:

> 001234

And, if you want to add a fixed number of zeroes, then you can just use (to add 3 leading zeroes):

> "000" + totext(your_number, 0);            // to add 3 leading zeroes

**Note: The final output is a string not a number.**

Answer (score 5):

To pad a *numeric* string value with zeroes to a certain length:

```
local numbervar yournum := tonumber({table.your_string}); //convert to number
totext(yournumnum, '000000') //convert back to padded string of length 6
```

OR for a universal string

```
local stringvar yourstring:= {table.your_string};
local numbervar LENGTH := 10; //The desired padded string length

if length(yourstring) >= LENGTH then yourstring else
  replicatestring('0',LENGTH-length(yourstring)) + yourstring
```

Answer (score 1):

how to use the formula in your crystal report,
to put below mention  formula in ( open (field explorer)-->then right click(Formula field)-->select new--->create formula name(xyz)-->then put 
** **ToText({DataTable1.Sr_No},"0000")** **

copy/past only bold text between ** and then save and close

after that formula you add to your crystal report and run, your required answer is there,

Sr_No.
0001
0002
0003

Answer (score 0):

just put on your field '0'+yourstringchar

Answer (score 0):

Above the logic works and its a generic formula to left padding

if you want right padding use this

```
  local stringvar yourstring:= {table.your_string};
  local numbervar LENGTH := 10; //The desired padded string length

  if length(yourstring) >= LENGTH 
        then yourstring 
  else
        yourstring + replicatestring('0',LENGTH-length(yourstring))
```

--kanthi

Answer (score 0):

```
Right("00000000"&ToText({Table.correla}),8)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
replace((space((20)-len({Table.Field}))+({Table.Field}))," ","0")
```

Basically it makes leading spaces, but then replaces those spaces with zeros.  By subtracting the length of the field from the added spaces, the field will always be the number of characters specified in **space((XX)**...

It looks overly-complex, but it actually simplifies reports that require numerous fixed-length fields.  As I develop the report, I can copy-paste this code to a new formula, change the number of spaces to match the required field length, then change my field name.